# Extending the typer of user the most simple way in Django

Tags: django-models, django-admin

I want to create two types of user in Django in the most simple way.

I want to use class AbstractBaseUser

```
class BaseUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)

class Service_provider(BaseUser):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=140);

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.company

class Customer(BaseUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140);

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.name
```

I don't know how to pass this two user to the user model without applying any complicated change in the auth model.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No. Django's built-in auth framework does not support more than one user model. You will need to write your own auth framework from scratch.

Comment: Can you tell me one link that describe the more simple and basic way to create two kind of users. I have a list of services and these services have service providers and customers. Thanks